# Faceing error from docker "Error response from daemon:" after apply docker compose pull

Tags: docker-compose

I am using docker version - 22 in my windows 10 pc. Now i am trying
to run a docker compose command in my sample java app. After run the
docker compose command : docker compose up -d , it gives bellow error.

error :

Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": net/http: TLS handshake timeout

[image]

Comment: You have given no information about your setup what so ever. How do you expect anyone to be able to help you? Please take the [tour], read [ask].